# Uncaught Error: Incompatible SockJS! - Angular 2 CLI

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server, sockjs

I have been getting the error:

```
'Uncaught Error: Incompatibile SockJS! Main site uses: "1.1.1", the iframe: "1.0.1".'
```

I was not getting this error until I added the following code to a service:

```
*COMPONENT*
this.dataService.getData(1,null).subscribe(
    result => this.allSCATSsites = result.json(),
    () => console.log("Failed..."),
    () => this.processSites()
);

*SERVICE*
getData(functionindex: number, dataarray) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post(url, sentArray,{
        headers: headers
    });
}
```

The weird problem is that I don't get the above error on every execution. it appears random.

I have no idea where to look or how to debug this - or if this even has anything to do with the Angular 2 CLI.  Research indicates something to do with Webpack dependencies within the Angular 2 CLI but I can't seem to pinpoint it - my package.json file doesn't have Webpack (or SockJS) within it, but Webpack is within my Node Modules folder.

Any ideas how to solve this or even where I should be looking?  I have tried upgrading to the latest version of the Angular 2 CLI and migrating the project to the new version also.

Comment: Please note that the misspelling of "Incompatibile" in the title was intentional, as it matches the exact output of the error.  As the error log has that misspelling, correcting the spelling may make it difficult for people to find this question.

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

One reason for this error may be the following (however, this would not account for the fact that your problem only occurred after adding the code mentioned above, and you didn't mention that you are using Websockets - so this may not solve your problem, but hopefully that of others):

If you have your requests routed through an HTTP server before they arrive at the application server, you have to make sure that the HTTP server lets the Websockets requests pass correctly.

When using Apache HTTP server, you could configure this like that (assuming that /myapp/ws is your websockets endpoint):

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/myapp/ws/(.*)/websocket$ ws://localhost:8080/myapp/ws/$1/websocket
```

For this to work, you must make sure that the proxy_wstunnel module is installed and enabled:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install apache2

sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
```

Note: If you haven't installed that correctly, then Spring Websockets will try a fallback to other options. In this case, an IFrame will be added which again loads a different socksjs library than that that you use in your application. And this will cause the error mentioned above.